# How to remove ?wp-mce from page source?

Tags: html, query-string

After check GT Metrix I found Remove query strings from static resources results is 50% and then found that's because some URL have ?wp-mce-4103-20162941 and no plugin can remove this so can use a code like this:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
   $parts = explode( '?wp-mce-', $src );
   return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

To solve the problem?

This's a example of the issue:

```
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/colorpicker/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/hr/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/tabfocus/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/textcolor/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpautoresize/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpdialogs/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpembed/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wptextpattern/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpview/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4103-20162941
```